# VB String Concatenation Incomplete

Tags: vb.net, string

I met a strange problem. I wanted to add string and string but it did not add together in actual.

Below is my code:

```
sql = "insert into Table (a,b,c,d) values ('" + a.value + "',b,'" + c.value + "',0)"
```

I use `MessageBox` to show this string and it just shows

```
insert into Table (a,b,c,d) values ('a
```

How can I modify it?

Comment: What is the value of `a.value`?

Comment: Please do a search on "VB string concatenation" for the basics of the language, and then do your yourself a **major** favor and research "parameterized queries" and "SQL injection" for the proper way to handle your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Always use an ampersand "&" when appending strings in VB.NET.

Change the code to

```
sql = "insert into Table (a,b,c,d) values ('" & a.value & "',b,'" & c.value & "',0)"
```

Comment: Or better yet, change to use a parameterized statement and eliminate the concatenation totally (and reduce the risk of SQL injection at the same time).

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, if I use `&`, it still breaks at `a.value`.

Comment: @CYB what is `a`? and what is the value of `a.value`?

Comment: @Damith It's a GUID string and it will be like `a7sh1-aj2d9-sj1hs-dj2h`.

Comment: @Damith Yes, I've tried your answer, thank you, but it still did not work.

Comment: @CYB Debug and check at run time what you have for those values, add Quick watch to your statement and try to change it and test, play around debugging you can find answer your self.

Comment: just a hunch, but does it make a difference if you try stringbuilder instead of taking sql as a string?

Answer (score 0):

you ca use `+` as below

```
sql = "insert into Table (a,b,c,d) values ('" + a.value.ToString() + "',b,'" + c.value.ToString() + "',0)"
```

you need to convert the values to string if they are already not strings

but here you specify `,b,` without `''`, if it is string then you need to add that as below

```
sql = "insert into Table (a,b,c,d) values ('" + a.value.ToString() + "','b','" + c.value.ToString() + "',0)"
```

if you using `&` operator then you don't need to convert to strings.  read more about this check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx) link.

all above for string Concatenation but regarding SQL statement I would recommend you to use parameterized SQL statement.

[How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)